# How to avoid cmd errors causing GUI dialogs?

Tags: windows, cmd

In my cmd batch files, how may I avoid OS errors causing GUI dialogs like this

http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/4792/betachriswindowedbetare.png

?

This prevents me using e.g. the Close box. I would like all errors reported to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to avoid cmd errors causing GUI dialogs?

In short: you can't.

Windows basically supports two types of (usermode) application types: console (mode) or windows (graphical).

However, there is nothing enforced here. Every console mode application may have GUI elements (e.g. popup a message box in case of an error) and every GUI application may start a console and issue stuff there (see [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 function).

So unless every application/command you call from your batch file either

- is a console application that does not exhibit some sort of GUI

or

- is a GUI application but has specific options to make it "behave" in a batch file / command line environment

there is no way to assure that what you seek.

Comment: Thanks Christian. In this particular instance I was able to code around by replacing the START /WAIT that caused the dialog with a straight call of the exe which does not.